# Managements wants to display city and manager details if more than one manager from same city

Tags: sql, rdbms

Refer the following table:[resort management system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKK3z.jpg)

Following query is used to retrieve the details:

```
select distinct m1.city, m1.name, m1.phone
from manager m1 join manager m2
       on m2.city=m1.city
       where m1.name!=m2.name
order by 1,2;
```

I am unable to understand the query. Can someone please explain?!

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand? `distinct`? `from`? `where`?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
manager m1 join manager m2
       on m2.city=m1.city
       where m1.name!=m2.name
```

This part finds all pairs of managers in the same city but with different names.

```sql
select distinct m1.city, m1.name, m1.phone
```

This part returns the first manager from every pair.

The result is every manager that's in a city with more than one manager.

This is a pretty common pattern in SQL, don't know any great textbooks or tutorials for SQL if you want more detail, but I'd assume most tutorials cover using self joins.